# How to connect mysql database from the diffarent server to localhost xampp in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have to connect database from my domain example ([www.test.com](http://www.test.com)) to other project on localhost xampp thought codeigniter platform.

I have tried below code in aplication/config/database.php

Note: I have not mentioned exact host name, database, username & password for security reasons.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX:3306',
    'username' => '****_cs_user',
    'password' => '********',
    'database' => '****_case_study',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to ensure that this options are correctly filled:

> ```
>  $db['default'] = array(
>      'dsn'   => '',
>      'hostname' => 'yourhostip',
>      'username' => 'yourmysluser',
>      'password' => 'yourmysqlpassword',
>      'database' => 'yourdb',
>      'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
>      'port'     => '3306'
>      // Rest of options
>   );
> ```

According to the Codeigniter [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html), you can separate the port from the hostname.

2. You should make sure that in your server is activated the remote access, by default is disabled. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/mysql-how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) to enable this feature.